# Android Eclipse Emulator trouble

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

For the past couple of days I have not been able to get the Android emulator in Eclipse to launch successfully. I've gotten several different errors including: process system isn't responding, app has unfortunately closed, and the emulator just squatting at the splash screen for hours. I have tried several things listed on the forum, but no luck. I thought if I posted my logcat output, someone may have an idea about what is going on.

```
 ?:??: W/?(?): --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
04-22 19:16:05.610: I/Vold(45): Vold 2.1 (the revenge) firing up
04-22 19:16:06.310: D/Vold(45): Volume sdcard state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
04-22 19:22:06.040: I/SystemServer(382): Entered the Android system server!
04-22 19:22:08.100: I/SystemServer(382): Waiting for installd to be ready.
04-22 19:22:08.110: I/SystemServer(382): Enabled StrictMode logging for WM Looper
04-22 19:22:08.110: I/Installer(382): connecting...
04-22 19:22:08.590: I/SystemServer(382): Power Manager
04-22 19:22:09.110: I/SystemServer(382): Activity Manager
04-22 19:22:11.540: I/ActivityManager(382): Memory class: 64
04-22 19:22:15.250: I/AppOps(382): No existing app ops /data/system/appops.xml; starting empty
04-22 19:22:22.950: I/UiThread(382): Enabled StrictMode logging for UI thread
04-22 19:22:26.470: I/IntentFirewall(382): Read new rules (A:0 B:0 S:0)
04-22 19:22:29.320: I/ActivityManager(382): Enabled StrictMode logging for AThread's Looper
04-22 19:22:29.410: I/SystemServer(382): Display Manager
04-22 19:22:29.700: I/SystemServer(382): Telephony Registry
04-22 19:22:30.320: I/SystemServer(382): Scheduling Policy
04-22 19:22:30.590: I/DisplayManagerService(382): Display device added: DisplayDeviceInfo{"Built-in Screen": 1280 x 720, 60.000004 fps, density 320, 320.0 x 320.0 dpi, touch INTERNAL, rotation 0, type BUILT_IN, FLAG_DEFAULT_DISPLAY, FLAG_ROTATES_WITH_CONTENT, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
04-22 19:22:30.670: I/SystemServer(382): Package Manager
04-22 19:22:31.750: W/FileUtils(382): Failed to chmod(/data/system/packages.list): libcore.io.ErrnoException: chmod failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-22 19:22:42.010: D/SELinuxMMAC(382): Couldn't find install policy /data/security/mac_permissions.xml
04-22 19:22:42.100: D/SELinuxMMAC(382): Using install policy file /system/etc/security/mac_permissions.xml
04-22 19:22:46.520: I/PackageManager(382): No settings file; creating initial state
04-22 19:22:46.690: W/PackageManager(382): Running ENG build: no pre-dexopt!
04-22 19:32:08.320: W/PackageParser(382): No actions in intent filter at /system/priv-app/Contacts.apk Binary XML file line #375
04-22 19:32:58.730: W/PackageParser(382): No actions in intent filter at /system/priv-app/Dialer.apk Binary XML file line #162
04-22 19:51:52.740: W/PackageParser(382): No actions in intent filter at /data/app/ApiDemos.apk Binary XML file line #2899
04-22 19:51:52.930: W/PackageParser(382): No actions in intent filter at /data/app/ApiDemos.apk Binary XML file line #2905
04-22 19:55:15.220: W/PackageManager(382): Package com.example.android.apis desires unavailable shared library com.example.will.never.exist; ignoring!
04-22 19:56:11.820: W/PackageManager(382): Package com.example.android.apis desires unavailable shared library com.example.will.never.exist; ignoring!
04-22 19:56:11.920: W/PackageManager(382): Package com.android.camera desires unavailable shared library com.google.android.media.effects; ignoring!
04-22 19:56:11.920: I/PackageManager(382): Time to scan packages: 2005.343 seconds
04-22 19:56:12.640: W/PackageManager(382): Not granting permission android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH to package com.android.quicksearchbox (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x8be45)
04-22 19:56:13.660: W/PackageManager(382): Unknown permission com.android.smspush.WAPPUSH_MANAGER_BIND in package com.android.phone
04-22 19:56:16.510: W/PackageManager(382): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.providers.calendar
04-22 19:56:16.510: W/PackageManager(382): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.cl in package com.android.providers.calendar
04-22 19:56:16.530: W/PackageManager(382): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.mail in package com.android.calendar
04-22 19:56:16.530: W/PackageManager(382): Not granting permission android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x9be45)
04-22 19:56:16.530: W/PackageManager(382): Not granting permission android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x9be45)
04-22 19:56:16.720: W/PackageManager(382): Not granting permission android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET to package com.android.widgetpreview (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x8be44)
04-22 19:56:16.870: W/PackageManager(382): Unknown permission android.permission.INSTALL_DRM in package com.android.mms
04-22 19:56:17.360: W/PackageManager(382): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.settings
04-22 19:56:19.080: W/PackageManager(382): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.ACCESS_GOOGLE_PASSWORD in package com.android.development
04-22 19:56:19.080: W/PackageManager(382): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.development
04-22 19:56:19.080: W/PackageManager(382): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.ALL_SERVICES in package com.android.development
04-22 19:56:19.080: W/PackageManager(382): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.YouTubeUser in package com.android.development
04-22 19:56:19.130: W/PackageManager(382): Not granting permission android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES to package com.svox.pico (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x8be45)
04-22 19:56:19.230: W/PackageManager(382): Not granting permission android.permission.DEVICE_POWER to package com.android.deskclock (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x48be45)
04-22 19:56:35.160: I/ProcessStatsService(382): Prepared write state in 4ms
04-22 19:56:35.170: I/SystemServer(382): Entropy Mixer
04-22 19:56:35.260: W/EntropyMixer(382): No existing entropy file -- first boot?
04-22 19:56:35.670: I/EntropyMixer(382): Writing entropy...
04-22 19:56:36.740: I/SystemServer(382): User Service
04-22 19:56:36.770: I/SystemServer(382): Account Manager
04-22 19:56:38.100: I/SystemServer(382): Content Manager
04-22 19:56:38.220: I/SystemServer(382): System Content Providers
04-22 19:57:08.280: D/SettingsProvider(382): Generated and saved new ANDROID_ID [a408e0de15535ee9] for user 0
04-22 19:57:09.030: I/SystemServer(382): Lights Service
04-22 19:57:10.140: I/SystemServer(382): Battery Service
04-22 19:57:11.590: I/SystemServer(382): Vibrator Service
04-22 19:57:11.970: I/SystemServer(382): Consumer IR Service
04-22 19:57:12.510: I/SystemServer(382): Alarm Manager
04-22 19:57:13.080: I/SystemServer(382): Init Watchdog
04-22 19:57:13.110: I/SystemServer(382): Input Manager
04-22 19:57:13.300: I/InputManager(382): Initializing input manager, mUseDevInputEventForAudioJack=false
04-22 19:57:13.810: I/SystemServer(382): Window Manager
04-22 19:57:16.040: I/WindowManager(382): No existing display settings /data/system/display_settings.xml; starting empty
04-22 19:57:26.080: I/WindowManager(382): No keyguard interface!
04-22 19:57:26.700: I/InputManager(382): Starting input manager
04-22 19:57:27.070: I/SystemServer(382): No Bluetooh Service (emulator)
04-22 19:57:27.070: I/SystemServer(382): Input Method Service
04-22 19:57:34.710: W/InputMethodManagerService(382): No IME selected. Choose the most applicable IME.
04-22 19:57:34.710: I/InputMethodManagerService(382): No default found, using com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME
04-22 19:57:36.840: I/SystemServer(382): Accessibility Manager
04-22 19:57:37.880: I/ActivityManager(382): Config changes=1df8 {1.0 ?mcc?mnc en_US ldltr sw360dp w640dp h360dp 320dpi nrml long land ?uimode ?night -touch -keyb/h/h -nav/h s.2}
04-22 19:57:38.680: I/ActivityManager(382): Config changes=408 {1.0 ?mcc?mnc en_US ldltr sw360dp w640dp h335dp 320dpi nrml long land ?uimode ?night finger -keyb/h/h -nav/h s.3}
04-22 19:57:39.240: I/SystemServer(382): Mount Service
04-22 19:57:39.760: D/MountService(382): got storage path: /storage/sdcard description: USB storage primary: true removable: false emulated: false mtpReserve: 0 allowMassStorage: false maxFileSize: 0
04-22 19:57:39.840: D/MountService(382): addVolumeLocked() StorageVolume:
04-22 19:57:39.840: D/MountService(382):     mStorageId=0 mPath=/storage/sdcard mDescriptionId=17040664 mPrimary=true 
04-22 19:57:39.840: D/MountService(382):     mRemovable=false mEmulated=false mMtpReserveSpace=0 
04-22 19:57:39.840: D/MountService(382):     mAllowMassStorage=false mMaxFileSize=0 mOwner=null mUuid=null 
04-22 19:57:39.840: D/MountService(382):     mUserLabel=null mState=null 
04-22 19:57:40.310: I/SystemServer(382): LockSettingsService
04-22 19:57:40.530: I/SystemServer(382): Device Policy
04-22 19:57:40.910: I/SystemServer(382): Status Bar
04-22 19:57:41.070: I/SystemServer(382): Clipboard Service
04-22 19:57:41.290: I/SystemServer(382): NetworkManagement Service
04-22 19:57:41.790: I/SystemServer(382): Text Service Manager Service
04-22 19:57:43.180: E/VoldConnector(382): NDC Command {1 volume list} took too long (2383ms)
04-22 19:57:43.220: D/MountService(382): volume state changed for /storage/sdcard (unmounted -> removed)
04-22 19:57:43.360: W/MountService(382): getSecureContainerList() called when storage not mounted
04-22 19:57:44.180: E/VoldConnector(382): NDC Command {2 asec list} took too long (819ms)
04-22 19:57:45.330: I/SystemServer(382): NetworkStats Service
04-22 19:57:45.540: W/PackageManager(382): Not granting permission android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH to package com.android.quicksearchbox (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x8be45)
04-22 19:57:46.420: I/SystemServer(382): NetworkPolicy Service
04-22 19:57:46.660: W/PackageManager(382): Unknown permission com.android.smspush.WAPPUSH_MANAGER_BIND in package com.android.phone
04-22 19:57:46.780: I/SystemServer(382): Wi-Fi P2pService
04-22 19:57:46.930: W/PackageManager(382): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.providers.calendar
04-22 19:57:46.930: W/PackageManager(382): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.cl in package com.android.providers.calendar
04-22 19:57:47.060: W/PackageManager(382): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.mail in package com.android.calendar
04-22 19:57:47.060: W/PackageManager(382): Not granting permission android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x9be45)
04-22 19:57:47.060: W/PackageManager(382): Not granting permission android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x9be45)
04-22 19:57:47.170: W/PackageManager(382): Not granting permission android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET to package com.android.widgetpreview (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x8be44)
04-22 19:57:47.280: W/PackageManager(382): Unknown permission android.permission.INSTALL_DRM in package com.android.mms
04-22 19:57:47.970: W/PackageManager(382): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.settings
04-22 19:57:52.670: W/PackageManager(382): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.ACCESS_GOOGLE_PASSWORD in package com.android.development
04-22 19:57:52.670: W/PackageManager(382): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.development
04-22 19:57:52.670: W/PackageManager(382): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.ALL_SERVICES in package com.android.development
04-22 19:57:52.670: W/PackageManager(382): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.YouTubeUser in package com.android.development
04-22 19:57:52.710: W/PackageManager(382): Not granting permission android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES to package com.svox.pico (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x8be45)
04-22 19:57:53.280: W/PackageManager(382): Not granting permission android.permission.DEVICE_POWER to package com.android.deskclock (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x48be45)
04-22 19:58:22.310: I/SystemServer(382): Wi-Fi Service
04-22 19:58:35.370: I/SystemServer(382): Connectivity Service
04-22 19:58:35.620: D/ConnectivityService(382): ConnectivityService starting up
04-22 19:58:36.470: D/ConnectivityService(382): wifiOnly=false
04-22 19:58:40.280: E/MobileDataStateTracker(382): default: Ignoring feature request because could not acquire PhoneService
04-22 19:58:40.280: E/MobileDataStateTracker(382): default: Could not enable APN type "default"
04-22 19:58:40.990: I/WifiService(382): WifiService starting up with Wi-Fi disabled
04-22 19:58:42.980: I/SystemServer(382): Network Service Discovery Service
04-22 19:58:43.210: D/NsdService(382): Network service discovery enabled true
04-22 19:58:43.470: I/SystemServer(382): UpdateLock Service
04-22 19:58:43.510: I/SystemServer(382): Notification Manager
04-22 19:58:44.690: I/SystemServer(382): Device Storage Monitor
04-22 19:58:45.280: I/SystemServer(382): Location Manager
04-22 19:58:45.410: I/SystemServer(382): Country Detector
04-22 19:58:45.490: I/SystemServer(382): Search Service
04-22 19:58:45.720: I/SystemServer(382): DropBox Service
04-22 19:58:46.060: I/SystemServer(382): Wallpaper Service
04-22 19:58:46.550: W/WallpaperService(382): no current wallpaper -- first boot?
04-22 19:58:46.600: I/SystemServer(382): Audio Service
04-22 19:59:09.830: I/SystemServer(382): Dock Observer
04-22 19:59:09.970: W/DockObserver(382): This kernel does not have dock station support
04-22 19:59:10.080: I/SystemServer(382): Wired Accessory Manager
04-22 19:59:10.260: W/WiredAccessoryManager(382): This kernel does not have wired headset support
04-22 19:59:10.260: W/WiredAccessoryManager(382): This kernel does not have usb audio support
04-22 19:59:10.370: W/WiredAccessoryManager(382): This kernel does not have HDMI audio support
04-22 19:59:10.450: I/SystemServer(382): USB Service
04-22 19:59:11.020: I/SystemServer(382): Serial Service
04-22 19:59:11.190: I/SystemServer(382): Twilight Service
04-22 19:59:11.660: I/SystemServer(382): UI Mode Manager Service
04-22 19:59:11.790: I/SystemServer(382): Backup Service
04-22 19:59:13.580: V/BackupManagerService(382): Initializing package tracking
04-22 19:59:13.580: V/BackupManagerService(382): No ancestral data
04-22 19:59:14.030: V/BackupManagerService(382): addPackageParticipantsLocked: all
04-22 19:59:14.030: I/BackupManagerService(382): Scheduling backup for new app com.android.calendar
04-22 19:59:14.110: D/BackupManagerService(382): Now staging backup of com.android.calendar
04-22 19:59:14.560: I/BackupManagerService(382): Scheduling backup for new app com.android.browser
04-22 19:59:14.610: D/BackupManagerService(382): Now staging backup of com.android.browser
04-22 19:59:14.800: I/BackupManagerService(382): Scheduling backup for new app com.android.providers.userdictionary
04-22 19:59:14.800: D/BackupManagerService(382): Now staging backup of com.android.providers.userdictionary
04-22 19:59:14.950: I/BackupManagerService(382): Scheduling backup for new app com.android.sharedstoragebackup
04-22 19:59:14.950: D/BackupManagerService(382): Now staging backup of com.android.sharedstoragebackup
04-22 19:59:15.210: I/BackupManagerService(382): Scheduling backup for new app android
04-22 19:59:15.210: D/BackupManagerService(382): Now staging backup of android
04-22 19:59:15.360: I/BackupManagerService(382): Scheduling backup for new app com.android.dialer
04-22 19:59:15.360: D/BackupManagerService(382): Now staging backup of com.android.dialer
04-22 19:59:15.660: I/BackupManagerService(382): Scheduling backup for new app com.android.providers.settings
04-22 19:59:15.690: D/BackupManagerService(382): Now staging backup of com.android.providers.settings
04-22 19:59:15.930: V/BackupManagerService(382): Starting with transport android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport
04-22 19:59:15.930: V/BackupManagerService(382): Found transports: 1
04-22 19:59:16.030: I/BackupManagerService(382): Binding to transport host ComponentInfo{android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransportService}
04-22 19:59:16.440: I/BackupManagerService(382): Backup enabled => true
04-22 19:59:16.460: I/SystemServer(382): AppWidget Service
04-22 19:59:18.760: I/SystemServer(382): Recognition Service
04-22 19:59:18.800: I/SystemServer(382): DiskStats Service
04-22 19:59:18.860: I/SystemServer(382): SamplingProfiler Service
04-22 19:59:19.160: I/SystemServer(382): NetworkTimeUpdateService
04-22 19:59:19.240: I/SystemServer(382): CommonTimeManagementService
04-22 19:59:19.370: I/SystemServer(382): CertBlacklister
04-22 19:59:19.580: I/SystemServer(382): Dreams Service
04-22 19:59:19.680: I/SystemServer(382): Assets Atlas Service
04-22 19:59:19.910: I/SystemServer(382): IdleMaintenanceService
04-22 19:59:19.980: I/SystemServer(382): Print Service
04-22 19:59:20.230: I/SystemServer(382): Media Router Service
04-22 19:59:35.130: I/LockSettingsService(382): Migrated lock settings to new location
04-22 19:59:36.330: W/ActivityManager(382): Timeout executing service: ServiceRecord{b23cf868 u0 android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransportService}
04-22 19:59:36.940: I/LockSettingsService(382): Migrated per-user lock settings to new location
04-22 20:00:19.300: E/ActivityManager(382): Attempt to launch receivers of broadcast intent Intent { act=android.net.ConnectivityService.action.PKT_CNT_SAMPLE_INTERVAL_ELAPSED flg=0x4 (has extras) } before boot completion
04-22 20:00:19.940: W/ActivityManager(382): Unable to send startActivity intent
04-22 20:00:19.940: W/ActivityManager(382): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot broadcast before boot completed
04-22 20:00:19.940: W/ActivityManager(382):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.verifyBroadcastLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:13675)
04-22 20:00:19.940: W/ActivityManager(382):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:13714)
04-22 20:00:19.940: W/ActivityManager(382):     at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:269)
04-22 20:00:19.940: W/ActivityManager(382):     at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.send(PendingIntentRecord.java:192)
04-22 20:00:19.940: W/ActivityManager(382):     at android.app.PendingIntent.send(PendingIntent.java:705)
04-22 20:00:19.940: W/ActivityManager(382):     at android.app.PendingIntent.send(PendingIntent.java:659)
04-22 20:00:19.940: W/ActivityManager(382):     at com.android.server.AlarmManagerService$AlarmThread.run(AlarmManagerService.java:1209)
04-22 20:00:22.960: I/ActivityManager(382): Start proc com.android.systemui for service com.android.keyguard/.KeyguardService: pid=459 uid=10007 gids={50007, 1028, 1015, 1035, 3002, 3001}
04-22 20:00:52.640: I/ActivityManager(382): Sending system update to ComponentInfo{com.android.providers.calendar/com.android.providers.calendar.CalendarUpgradeReceiver} for user 0
04-22 20:00:52.640: I/ActivityManager(382): Sending system update to ComponentInfo{com.android.providers.contacts/com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsUpgradeReceiver} for user 0
04-22 20:00:52.760: I/ActivityManager(382): Sending system update to ComponentInfo{com.android.providers.media/com.android.providers.media.MediaUpgradeReceiver} for user 0
04-22 20:00:52.760: I/SystemServer(382): Enabled StrictMode for system server main thread.
04-22 20:00:56.760: W/InputMethodManagerService(382): Focus gain on non-focused client android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$1@b20039d8 (uid=1000 pid=382)
04-22 20:00:56.900: V/BackupManagerService(382): Connected to transport ComponentInfo{android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransportService}
04-22 20:00:56.970: V/BackupManagerService(382): Registering transport android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransportService::android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport = com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport@b20f2000
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382): ANR in system
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382): PID: 382
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382): Reason: Executing service android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransportService
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382): Load: 5.73 / 4.47 / 3.69
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382): CPU usage from 0ms to 115388ms later with 99% awake:
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):   55% 50/surfaceflinger: 14% user + 41% kernel / faults: 5 minor
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):   15% 94/bootanimation: 2.6% user + 12% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):   14% 382/system_server: 7.8% user + 6.7% kernel / faults: 1472 minor 2 major
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):   0.1% 48/debuggerd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1329 minor
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):   0% 61/adbd: 0% user + 0% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):   0.2% 25/mtdblock0: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):   0.2% 26/mtdblock1: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):   0% 51/zygote: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 75 minor
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):   0.1% 55/kworker/0:2: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):   0% 44/servicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):   0% 40/jbd2/mtdblock1-: 0% user + 0% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):   0% 53/mediaserver: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 4 minor
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):   0% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):   0% 425/flush-31:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):   0% 7/sync_supers: 0% user + 0% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):   0% 54/installd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 5 minor
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):  +0% 459/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 0% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382): 100% TOTAL: 33% user + 65% kernel + 0.5% softirq
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382): CPU usage from 99869ms to 106809ms later:
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):   61% 50/surfaceflinger: 18% user + 43% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):     40% 50/surfaceflinger: 11% user + 28% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):     7.1% 80/DispSync: 1.8% user + 5.2% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):     3.8% 91/EventThread: 1.6% user + 2.1% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):     2.6% 79/Binder_2: 1.4% user + 1.1% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):     2.3% 104/Binder_3: 0.6% user + 1.6% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):     1.9% 106/Binder_4: 0.3% user + 1.6% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):     1.6% 78/Binder_1: 0.4% user + 1.1% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):     1.3% 107/Binder_5: 0.1% user + 1.1% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):   11% 382/system_server: 6.5% user + 5.3% kernel / faults: 56 minor
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):     5.8% 397/ActivityManager: 3.1% user + 2.7% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):     2.3% 389/Compiler: 1.6% user + 0.7% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):     1.3% 394/Binder_2: 0.9% user + 0.3% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):     1.1% 396/WindowManager: 0.4% user + 0.7% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):     0.4% 393/Binder_1: 0.1% user + 0.3% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):     0.3% 398/android.bg: 0.1% user + 0.2% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):     0.2% 453/Binder_3: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):     0.1% 395/SensorService: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):   14% 94/bootanimation: 2.1% user + 12% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):     22% 103/BootAnimation: 3.3% user + 18% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):   9.1% 459/com.android.systemui: 5.1% user + 4% kernel / faults: 280 minor
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):     6.7% 459/ndroid.systemui: 3.8% user + 2.8% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):     1.8% 466/Compiler: 0.8% user + 1% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):    +0% 475/SoundPool: 0% user + 0% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):    +0% 476/SoundPoolThread: 0% user + 0% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382):   0.8% 55/kworker/0:2: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
04-22 20:01:37.420: E/ActivityManager(382): 100% TOTAL: 34% user + 65% kernel + 0.6% softirq
04-22 20:01:38.700: I/ActivityManager(382): Start proc com.android.providers.calendar for broadcast com.android.providers.calendar/.CalendarUpgradeReceiver: pid=479 uid=10001 gids={50001, 3003, 1028, 1015}
04-22 20:01:47.410: I/ActivityManager(382): Launching preboot mode app: ProcessRecord{b24c90d0 479:com.android.providers.calendar/u0a1}
04-22 20:02:31.630: W/WindowManager(382): Window freeze timeout expired.
04-22 20:02:31.630: W/WindowManager(382): Force clearing orientation change: Window{b23b3690 u0 Application Not Responding: system}
: E/(): LogCat Connection error
: E/(): Device disconnected: 1
: E/(): Device disconnected
```

Comment: did u try to run a simple hello world application because it seems that you're getting quite some errors from your app and it using permissions

Comment: No, but I am trying that right now.

Comment: try that - and maybe also try another avd (a predefined)

Comment: Get the error message: emulator disconnected! cancelling com.example.Helloworld.MainActivity

Comment: it's hard to tell.. things you can try: start the avd without running a project (window->avd Manager->choose avd click start select "wipe user data") ... and other thing you can try is: delete current avd and add a new one

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already tried that with no success : (

Comment: yeah.. that happens because eclipse was built on a cemetery.. poltergeist all over

Comment: LOL...yes! I agree! It sucks. But thank you for the suggestions.